# How do I make a square hole in a cube, and then save it as one mesh?

Tags: modeling

I need to design a thick slit, in which i will place a lever, kind of like a large power switch that mad scientists have. I was wondering how to make the slit, and save as one mesh. Would really help if someone could tell me how to make the lever as well.

Answer (score 10):

1. In edit mode, select the top face of your cube.
2. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> and resize the new face till it is the size you need.
3. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the hole inward.
4. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> and choose *Faces* to delete the bottom face of your hole.

[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the *Boolean* modifier. This works great cause it makes the trench the exact size of the object embedded in it.

Create the objects, if needed create a separate object that is the size and shape you want your trench to be, the add a Boolean modifier to the block, with the handle or trench object as the target and the type set to *difference*.

Here are pictures of two different "evil genius switch's" (that a thing now :) made using the Boolean modifier.

[image]

[image]